# How to get telegram bot chat_id?

Tags: telegram, telegram-bot

Do telegram bot can send a message to himself?
Need to my bot on start send a message to himself.
Is there such a possibility?

Comment: Can you describe your case? It's not clear what you are trying to achieve.

You can send a message to client as a reply to /start command. Why would your bot want to use API to send message to itself? You obviously should be able to make it internally?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, bots can't send message to each other or to them self.